# Delphi: Using generics to accept any "callable" (e.g. procedure, procedure of object, lambda)

Tags: delphi, generics, callable

In C++ duck typing there is the concept of a callable, e.g. a symbol that can be called like a function. I'd like to emulate this with Delphi generics.

I have a problem where I need a procedure that can accept either a normal procedure, a class method or a lambda as argument. Right now I have 3 almost identical overloaded implementations. Is there a way to use Delphi generics to avoid this duplication?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need generics for this.

The `reference to X` is compatible with `X`, `X of object`, and `reference to X` (where `X` is a procedural type such as `procedure(X: Integer)`).

For example,

```pascal
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TTestProc = procedure(X: Integer);
  TTestMeth = procedure(X: Integer) of object;
  TTestRef = reference to procedure(X: Integer);

// Ordinary procedure
procedure TestProc(X: Integer);
begin
end;

// Method
type
  TMyClass = class
    class procedure TestMeth(X: Integer);
  end;

class procedure TMyClass.TestMeth(X: Integer);
begin
end;

begin
  var A: TTestRef;
  A := TestProc;
  A := TMyClass.TestMeth;
  A := procedure(X: Integer) begin end;
end.
```

Comment: Generic [TProc](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TProc) and [TFunc](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFunc) from RTL are worth mentioning here. Note that they don't have `const` modifier on their parameters, which can be an issue with auto ref. counted types like strings.